# robot_pose_ekf does not publish anything

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to use robot_pose_ekf with imu data but it does not produce any output .

output of :rostopic hz /robot_pose_ekf/odom

> subscribed to [/robot_pose_ekf/odom]

launch file :

> < launch>   < node pkg="robot_pose_ekf"
> type="robot_pose_ekf"
> name="robot_pose_ekf" output="screen">
> <param name="output_frame"
> value="odom"/>  
>    < param name="freq"
> value="30.0"/>   
>   <param
> name="sensor_timeout" value="1.0"/>
> <param name="publish_tf"
> value="true"/>  
>    < param
> name="odom_used" value="false"/>
>
> < param name="imu_used" value="true"/>
>
> < param name="vo_used" value="false"/>

output of : rostopic hz /imu_data

> subscribed to [/imu_data]
>  average
> rate: 8.382
>   min: 0.115s max:
> 0.126s std dev: 0.00357s window: 8
>  average rate: 8.350
>   min:
> 0.115s max: 0.126s std dev: 0.00306s window: 16
>  average rate:
> 8.333
>     min: 0.115s max: 0.126s std dev: 0.00301s window: 24

output of : rostopic echo /imu_data

> header: 
>    seq: 780
>    stamp:
>
> secs: 1385929326
> nsecs: 189629077
>    frame_id: base_link
>  orientation: 
>    x:
> 0.103565725066
>    y: 0.10414370554
>    z: 0.000989699922996
>    w: 0.989154815831
>  orientation_covariance: [0.0, 0.0,
> 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
>  angular_velocity: 
>    x: 0.0
>    y: 0.0
>    z: 0.0
>  angular_velocity_covariance: [0.0,
> 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
>  linear_acceleration: 
>    x: 40.0
>    y: -39.0
>    z:
> -1004.0
>  linear_acceleration_covariance: [0.0,
> 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
> ---

Please help

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/106166/robot_pose_ekf-does-not-publish-anything/) by [7mdan92](https://answers.ros.org/users/9371/7mdan92/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2013-12-01

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ahmed_Desoky](https://answers.ros.org/users/49283/ahmed_desoky/) on 2020-05-31**:
Are you solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The robot pose ekf will not start when it only receives imu messages; it also expects messages on either the visual odometry message or the odometry message.

---

Originally posted by [cagatay](https://answers.ros.org/users/2526/cagatay/) with karma: 1850 on 2013-12-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3